# I am getting text error while the code is appicable for on company using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.yelu.in/category/advertising')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

for links in soup.find_all('a',class_='m_company_link'):
    href = links['href']

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Googleboat'}
r = requests.get("https://www.yelu.in/"+href,headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
company = {
    "company_name" : soup.select_one('#company_name').text,
    "address" : soup.select_one('div.text.location').text,
    "phone" : soup.select_one('div.text.phone').text,
    "mobile_phone" : soup.find('div',string = "Mobile 
     phone").find_next_sibling('div').text,
    "fax": soup.find('div',string = "Fax").find_next_sibling('div').text,
    "website" : soup.find('div',string = 
    "Website").find_next_sibling('div').text,
    "year" :soup.find('span',string = "Establishment year").next_sibling,
    "employees" :soup.find('span',string = "Employees").next_sibling,
    "manager" :soup.find('span',string = "Company manager").next_sibling
}
print(company)
```

i am getting this below error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\yelu.py", line 14, in 
    "company_name" : soup.select_one('#company_name').text,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

> > > "

Answer (score 0):

Your URL construction is wrong. Get rid of the double // in

```
in/" + href
```

ie:

```
in" + href
```

If you check your current response you are getting page not found.

See output from:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Googleboat'}
r = requests.get('https://www.yelu.in/category/advertising') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

for links in soup.find_all('a',class_='m_company_link'): 
    href = links['href']
    try:
        r = requests.get("https://www.yelu.in/" + href, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
        company = {
        "company_name" : soup.select_one('#company_name').text,
        "address" : soup.select_one('div.text.location').text,
        "phone" : soup.select_one('div.text.phone').text,
        "mobile_phone" : soup.find('div',string = "Mobile phone").find_next_sibling('div').text,
        "fax": soup.find('div',string = "Fax").find_next_sibling('div').text,
        "website" : soup.find('div',string = "Website").find_next_sibling('div').text,
        "year" :soup.find('span',string = "Establishment year").next_sibling,
        "employees" :soup.find('span',string = "Employees").next_sibling,
        "manager" :soup.find('span',string = "Company manager").next_sibling
         }
        print(company)
    except AttributeError as e:
        print("https://www.yelu.in/" + href, r.status_code)
```

---

Sample output:

[image]